# How to unit test $http in angularjs and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Here is my code, I've made a Plunker as the code is long:

```
 describe("create", function(){
        it("Should be defined", function(){
            expect(BaseService.create).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("it should POST to http://api.test.com/TEST/", function(){

          /***
           * 
           * NOT TO SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
           * 
           */

        })
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/s8P2XlkfR6HfGuj8WIcb

I am new to Unit Testing so I am having a bit of trouble working out how to assert the following:

1. If the method is going to x url
2. If the method is using x method (e.g. GET, PUT, POST or DELETE)
3. If the data passed to the method is the same as the data that is sent in the call
4. If the return type of the method is a Promise
5. If the contents of the Promise matches the expected type.

On a side note I am also open to suggestions for things I should also test.

Comment: Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend, and try something.

Comment: @JBNizet given very good reference to for unit testing of $http..It will helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use httpBackend mock service that will help to test your $http.

```
describe('Myctrl', function() {

   var $httpBackend, scope, createController, authRequestHandler;

   // Set up the module
   beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

   beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

     // Set up the mock http service responses

     $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

     // backend definition common for all tests

     authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'service.json')
                            .respond(true);

     // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)

     $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

     // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
     var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');


     createController = function() {

       return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : scope});

     };

   })

);


   afterEach(function() {

     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();

     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();


   });

   it('should fetch authentication token', function() {

     $httpBackend.expectGET('service.json');

     var controller = createController();

     expect(scope.names).toBe(true); 

     $httpBackend.flush();

   });


});
```