# Jasmine unit tests with odata promises

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise, odata

I'm new at angular and at unit testing with angular. We are using odata for database CRUD actions, so we have created a service for that, looks like this:

```
function DatabaseService($http, $odataresource, DateFactory, constants) {

    var url = constants.BACKEND.URL;
    var ObjCreate = $odataresource(url + 'Objects/Function.CreateObject', {}, {}, {});

    var service = {
        createSomething: {
            createObj: createObj
        }};

    return service;

    function createObj(formData) {
        var myObj = new ObjCreate();
        mapData(formData, myObj );
        return myObj.$save();
    }
```

The code is a bit abstracted for my question, so don't wonder please. I want to unit test the `function createObj()` now, which doesn't work. I took an angular class and we learned there that for 'execute' promises we have to use `$rootScope.digest()`, but it doesn't seem to work in my case:

```
    describe('createObj', function () {

    it('should return data', inject(function ($rootScope) {

        var DatabaseService = $injector.get('DatabaseService', { $odataresource: $odataresource });

        var formDataMock = {
            productName: "Produktname"
        };

        var test = 'abc';

        DatabaseService.createSomething.createObj(formDataMock)
            .then(function (data) {
                test = data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                test = error;
            });

        $rootScope.$digest();

        console.log(test);
    }));
```

I have added the setting of the variable test to see when for example the then path is executed, but even with the `$rootScope.$digest` it will never step into the then path, my variable test will never change from 'abc' to something else.

Could you please give me a hint what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test $http in angularjs and Jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108273/how-to-unit-test-http-in-angularjs-and-jasmine)

Comment: Maybe this two links are helpful: 
http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine/ 
http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine_Provide_Spy/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to update your code to use the done Feature of Jasmine 2.0.
http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine/

```js
 describe('createObj', function () {

    it('should return data', function (done) {

        var DatabaseService = $injector.get('DatabaseService', { $odataresource: $odataresource });

        var formDataMock = {
            productName: "Produktname"
        };

        var test = 'abc';

        DatabaseService.createSomething.createObj(formDataMock)
            .then(function (data) {
                test = data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                test = error;
            })
  .finally(done);;

        console.log(test);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that.